# Confused about error message (lldb)

Tags: swift, null

Say for example 13 was entered into the text field which is referenced by: numberField

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

            var numInt = numberField.text.toInt()

            println(numInt) //outputs Optional(13)
            println(numInt!) //outputs 13

            if numInt != nil {

                var unwrappedNum = numInt!
                var isPrime = true
                println(unwrappedNum) //Crashes here and outputs (lldb)

                for var i = 1; i<unwrappedNum; i++ {
                    if unwrappedNum % i == 0 {
                        isPrime = false

                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I've checked online and I think the problem is that it is evaluating to nil but I don't understand how it would evaluate to nil when just outside the if statement it isn't nil.

Comment: Which kind of exception does it show?

Comment: Strange, I tried your code in the playground and it seems to work.

Comment: Looks like some hick-up. Have you tried it the windoze-way and rebooted?

Comment: It just shows (lldb)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `nil` check, the swift way to do it is to use **optional binding**.

```
if let unwrappedNum = numInt
{
    println(unwrappedNum)
}
```

or simply you can do

```
if let numInt = numberField.text.toInt()
{
    println(numInt)
}
```

`numInt` will be unwrapped.

For more info read : http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/

Comment: Actually the difference is just that this is thread save. It would not explain above behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I saw your problem is:

```
var numInt = numberField.text.toInt()
```

When "numberField.Text" is an empty String, it crashes.

Comment: No. As long as it's not unwrapped it's ok.

Comment: I try it in playground and it fails here when the numberField.text is empty.

Comment: But the field isn't empty when I test it in the ios simulator I do enter a number!